# Angular 5 сохранить данные в поле при переключении

Tags: typescript, angular

Есть модель:

```
form: FormGroup;
model = {
    CATS: {
        label: 'Кошки',
        values: [
            { name: 'petName', label: 'Имя питомца', value: '' },
            { name: 'doctorName', label: 'Имя врача', value: ''},

        ]
    },
    DOG: {
        label: 'Собаки',
        values: [
            { name: 'petName', label: 'Имя питомца', value: '' },
            { name: 'doctorName', label: 'Имя врача', value: '' },
        ]
    },
};
```

Переключение между кошками и собаками с помощью `<mat-chip-list>`. Как запомнить вводимые данные поля "Имя врача", чтобы при переключении вкладок оно запоминалось и отображалось одинаково в обеих вкладках?
[Код тут](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-okdchs).

Comment: подписываешься на изменение значения формы, сохраняешь измененное значение в модель

Comment: this.form.controls['doctorName'].valueChanges.subscribe (value => {
  console.log(value);
});
так подписываться?

Comment: да, так, только не забудь отписаться

Comment: а как сохранить в модель значение? Я пробовал, в консоли прописывается, а поля на форме все равно пустые при переключении вкладок

Comment: проверяешь какая форма сейчас активная, идешь в `this.models[type].values[name].value = value`

Comment: `changeType(type) { // проверяется вкладка

  this.activeType = this.model[type];
  this.activeFields = this.activeType.values;
  
  this.constructForm();  

    this.form.controls['doctorName'].valueChanges.subscribe (value => { console.log(this.model[type].values[1].value = value);  
    });
   
  this.sendForm();
 }`
Не получается ((

Answer (score 0):

Подправил, работает https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-okdchs-2oqez7

поля пустые, потому что в constructForm ты создаешь форму с пустыми значениями + ошибки в inputChange